# XRAY scanning of conda-forge / cran packages

Tags: artifactory, cran, conda-forge, jfrog-xray

I've been looking into scanning my Remote conda-forge and cran repositories with JFROG Xray but it seems like it's not natively [supported](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/JFrog+Xray). So naturally if I make a watch the remote-repositories of conda-forge and cran are not available to be scanned.

Has anyone ran into this problem of wanting to scan conda or cran packages in XRAY, fixed it, and would be willing to give a few pointers on how you achieved it?

Answer (score 1):

Conda and Cran scanning is still not supported but is in the near future roadmap of Xray.